# import {angular} from 'angular' is not working in AngularJS(1.5)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, module, node-modules

AngularJS - 1.5
TypeScript - 1.8.10
WebPack - 1.15.0

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings",
    "dist"
  ],
  
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

I am getting *ERROR in ./src/main/frontend/app/leftmenu/index.ts
(1,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'.* while i do a npm run build

***index.ts***

```
import {angular} from 'angular';
import {MenuService} from './menuService';
import {LeftMenuController} from './leftmenu';


angular.module('tat')
.service('MenuService', MenuService)
.component('leftMenu',{
          template : require('./leftmenu.html'),
           controller : LeftMenuController,
           controllerAs : 'lm'
       });
```

***Please tell me how do I make the angular module visible to my index.ts***

Note :: The angular module is present inside the node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should import AngularJS as a default module. Also suggest to export as default your services and components as angular modules. This let you manage all your stuff as ES6 modules.

```
   import angular from 'angular';
   import MenuServiceMod from './menuService';
   import LeftMenuComponentMod from './leftmenu';

   export default angular.module('tat', [
     MenuServiceMod,
     LeftMenuComponentMod
   ]);

   // component leftmenu.js
   const compConfig = {
      template : require('./leftmenu.html'),
       controller : LeftMenuController,
       controllerAs : 'lm'
   };
   function LeftMenuController() {
   // component logic
   }
   let compMod = angular.module('LeftMenuMod', []).component('leftMenu', compConfig);
   export default compMod = compMod.name;

   // service menuService.js
   class MenuService {
   // service logic
   }
   let svcMod = angular.module('MenuServiceMod', []).service('MenuService', MenuService);
   export default svcMod = svcMod.name;
```